# Conditional lateral flatten in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a table with json `variant`s that contain keys which may or may not be there depending on the API response.

example table:

```
create or replace temporary table test (variant_col variant);

insert into test(variant_col)
select parse_json('{"response": [{"key1":[1,2,3]}, {"key2":[7,8,9]}]}');
insert into test(variant_col)
select parse_json('{"response": [{"key2":[7,8,9]}]}');
```

I'd like to lateral flatten them based on their keys, and use `key1` if it exists, else use `key2` (which will always exist)

```
SELECT
    iff(f2.value::int is null, 'key2', 'key1') as value_type,
    ifnull(f2.value::int, f3.value::int) as desired_value
FROM
    test,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => response) as f1,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => f1.value:key1) as f2,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => f1.value:key2) as f3
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `flatten` is excluding the row from the result set, you can use OUTER => true, which will return a null row for zero-row expansions

```
SELECT
    iff(f2.value::int is null, 'key2', 'key1') as value_type,
    ifnull(f2.value::int, f3.value::int) as desired_value
FROM
    test,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => variant_col:response) as f1,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => f1.value:key1) as f2,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => f1.value:key2, OUTER => true) as f3
;
```

> If TRUE, exactly one row is generated for zero-row expansions (with
> NULL in the KEY, INDEX, and VALUE columns).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this by giving an id to each row, and then we can `union all` the results of 2 queries - depending on the existence of `key1`:

```sql
with data as (
    select row_number() over(order by 0) id, * 
    from test
), rows_with_key1 as (
    select data.*, value v
    from data
        , lateral flatten(input => variant_col:response) as f1
    where f1.value:key1 is not null
), rows_without_key1 as (
    select data.*, value v
    from data
        , lateral flatten(input => variant_col:response) as f1
    where id not in (select id from rows_with_key1)
)


select id, value, variant_col
from rows_with_key1
    , lateral flatten(input => v:key1) ff
union all
select id, value, variant_col
from rows_without_key1
    , lateral flatten(input => v:key2)
;
```